# Как правильно реализовать кодировку для дерева Хаффмана?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Пишу архиватор на основе алгоритма Хаффмана, есть готовое дерево. Когда пытаюсь задать кодировку для него, то при больших файлах размер бита получается от 8 до 10. При относительно небольших тоже расчёт кодировка начинается от 4-6 битов. Вот сам код кодировки

```
    public String getCodes(Byte by, String parentPath) {
    if (b == by)
        return parentPath;
    else {
        if (left != null) {
            String path = left.getCodes(by, parentPath + 0);
            if (path != null)
                return path;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            String path = right.getCodes(by, parentPath + 1);
            if (path != null)
                return path;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Извините а в чем проблема?

Comment: В том что нету смысла в такой кодировке, если 1 закодированный байт будет занимать больше чем 8 бит

Comment: Ну так это самый простой алгоритм сжатия. И при больших данных он очевидно сжимать если и будет, то не значительно. Я как то пытался сжать видео в 3 секунды так там, пару байт с экономил только.

Comment: Если у вас, скажем, 256 символов, и популярные вы кодируете коротко, то непопулярные будут закодированы числом бит больше восьми. Это неизбежно: [сжатие без потерь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C#%D0%A1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)